# Cannot use a property to index a generic type which should always have that property

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

### Objective

The goal is to make a fetch function which takes in the route and method as args, and the return type should be the type defined by the corresponding `response` property from an interface called `ScoresRoutes`.

In the `ScoresRoutes` interface, the top level keys of the object can be any string - representing a route. Each of these keys should be an object which has any of a fixed set of strings - which would be the HTTP method. Lastly, each route and method combo should be an object which always has a `response` property.

---

### Behavior

My current solution *does* work when I go to use the custom fetch function I made. In the last line of the below code, the type of `data` *is* the correct type - even when I add other routes and methods to the `ScoresRoutes` interface - and TypeScript throws errors if I try to use `customFetch` with an invalid route and method pair.

However, TypeScript still shows an error in the function definition, saying that `Type '"response"' cannot be used to index type 'ScoresRoutes[R][M]'`.

I could just silence the error considering I have the functionality I want, but I imagine that the error is an indication that I'm going about this the wrong way.

---

### Code

This is my broader type to describe the general shape of the desired interface:

```
type RequestMethod = 'GET' | 'POST' | 'PATCH' | 'DELETE';
type GenericRoutes<Paths extends string> = {
  [P in Paths]: {
    [M in RequestMethod]?: {
      request?: Record<string, unknown>,
      response: Record<string, unknown> | null,
      params?: Record<string, unknown>
    }
  }
}
```

Then here I have a specific implementation of it:

```
type ScoresPath = '/';
interface ScoresRoutes extends GenericRoutes<ScoresPath> {
  '/': {
    'GET': {
      response: {
        test: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And lastly, this is the custom fetch method I've created:

```
async function customFetch<
  R extends ScoresPath,
  M extends keyof ScoresRoutes[R]
>(
  route: R,
  method: M
): Promise<ScoresRoutes[R][M]['response']> { // This is where the TS error shows
  const data = await fetch(route, { method: method as string }).then((res) => res.json());
  return data;
}

customFetch('/', 'GET').then((data) => null); // `data` does have the proper type here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are getting this error because the `response` field may not actually exist. This is because the object returns from `ScoresRoutes[R][M]` may be undefined.

One way to work around this is to use a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#handbook-content), which will allow you to check the type of object you're getting prior to accessing the `response` property. Here is how you could do it:

```
type GenericRoutes<Paths extends string> = {
    [P in Paths]: {
        [M in RequestMethod]?: RequestMethodFields
    }
}

// Extracted as a separate type
interface RequestMethodFields {
    request?: Record<string, unknown>,
    response: Record<string, unknown> | null,
    params?: Record<string, unknown>
}

// New type; we no longer get an error accessing 'response' because we have already
// checked that we have the correct type of object
type MethodResponse<
  R extends keyof ScoresRoutes,
  M extends keyof ScoresRoutes[R]
> = ScoresRoutes[R][M] extends RequestMethodFields ? ScoresRoutes[R][M]['response'] : {}

async function customFetch<
    R extends keyof ScoresRoutes,
    M extends keyof ScoresRoutes[R]
>(
    route: R,
    method: M
): Promise<MethodResponse<R, M>> { // This is where the TS error shows
    const data = await fetch(route, { method: method as string }).then((res) => res.json());
    return data;
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShCOBXCBnYBZCwAWB7AJlALxQDkA4gKIAqpUAPmQAoDyAyrQ8wILUDCACTqNSAEUoAZGpVIBuAFChIUchAB2EAE4BLAMYxciYKgA8TAIY4UUCAA9ja-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-MF8g8AApTppdUUl1BgSr8PF0PIAJTxJjH4HaPGY-DYk14mAbdAeWOneZrmAKB8EscxvHMfZzG0YDOiHbB92PBkNh8c9L3iC9ykIesoCeNwoEaW8ADocHUfdENQW9iC8c4iIAKxQK591vW8FHGLBEE0CJQOAcwFFaHs+wHeD9wTDYKBoUhiNItRyJ48wqKILwvh+VigA)

Comment: Ahh I see, I thought that with how I had set up the generic `R` and `M` parameters that doing `ScoresRoutes[R][M]` would be guaranteed to exist. I'd never used conditional types before but this makes sense and works perfectly - thank you so much!